# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ontooltest\OntoolService'.
>
> Failed to run as a self-contained app.
>
> The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ontooltest\OntoolService\Itm.Web.Api.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
> If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ontooltest\OntoolService\Itm.Web.Api.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.

I have tried by removing the `wwwroot` folder and re-deployed again but it's not solved my problem. Also tried by putting the following lines in `.csproj` but won't help either

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please describe more details about what's your application? How you deploy the application?